# Would a sub query work for this situation?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following 6 tables

Districts - contains the district id and district name

District_access - used to identify which districts a user has access to

operation_centers - contains the ops center id and name

ops_access - used to identify which ops centers a user has access to

projects- contains project id and name

project_access - used to identify which projects a user has access to

I'm currently using this query and it returns the districts,ops centers and projects a user has access to. The problem is that if a user has access to district 4 only I would not see any of the other districts on my edit page, i only see district 4 and the ops centers and projects under district 4. I need to see the other districts so a user could be assign access to other districts, op center and projects, etc., would a subquery help with this?

```
   select district_access_id,district_user_nm,district_role,district_id,district_name,operation_center_id,operation_center_name,oc_district_id,project_name_id,project_name,project_oc_id
from district_access
left join districts ON district_access.district_access_id = districts.district_id
left join operation_centers ON districts.district_id = operation_centers.oc_district_id
left join projects ON operation_centers.operation_center_id = projects.project_oc_id
where district_user_nm = '#URL.user_id#' AND oc_district_id <> '' and project_oc_id <> '' OR district_user_nm = ''
```

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Sounds more like you need an outer join.

Comment: Maybe just simply take away "WHERE" clause?

Comment: cannot remove where clause. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main table (FROM) should be the user table, not district access. A cross join from your user to all districts will get you all the permutations of that user and all districts (or you could left join on an arbitrary statement like ON 1=1). Also, you should use parentheses in your WHERE because of that OR to ensure the logic is clearly defined.

```
select district_access_id,district_user_nm,district_role,district_id,district_name,operation_center_id,operation_center_name,oc_district_id,project_name_id,project_name,project_oc_id
from <USERNAME TABLE>
cross join districts
left join district_access ON district_access.district_access_id = districts.district_id
   and <USERNAME TABLE>.user_nm = '#URL.user_id#'
left join operation_centers ON districts.district_id = operation_centers.oc_district_id
left join projects ON operation_centers.operation_center_id = projects.project_oc_id
where <USERNAME TABLE>.user_nm = '#URL.user_id#'
    AND oc_district_id <> ''
    and project_oc_id <> ''
    OR district_user_nm = ''
```

Comment: I got this to work, thank you so much. I was beating my head against the wall on this one.